# Python - Get html table element with lxml.html regex

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to get the following element of the following website: https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/

[image]

I am using python request and lxml.html:

```
import requests
import lxml.html

payload= {
 'country[]': [25,32],
 'limit_from': 0,
 'submitFilters': 1,
 'timeFilter': 'timeRemain',
 'currentTab': 'today',
 'timeZone': 55}
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0','X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

r=requests.post("https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/",
                               data=payload, headers=headers) 
html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
results = html.xpath("//table[@id='economicCalendarData']//tr")
```

Lets consider here that the 3rd item in the list `results` is the one of interest. Those elements from the column "actual" have in common the suffix "actual" in the class attribute of the td. But the int before that and the font style varies. So I would like to use a regex in my xpath expression only locating the suffix "actual".

I have been trying
`results[3].find(".//td[contains(@class,'actual')]")`

and

`results[3].find(".//td[substring(@class, string-length(@class)-6)='actual']")`

(both from other SO questions) but both return `SyntaxError: invalid predicate`.

Can anyone help me find the correct xpath regexp expression to locate that `td`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from Upwork. I guess this is what you want

```
results[3].xpath("//td[contains(@class,'actual')]")
```